# Apache2: how to log rejected connections and client timeout

Tags: apache2, http.sys

I am doing some load testing on a service run with Apache2 and my load testing tool has a default timeout of 30 seconds. When I run the tool for a minute with 1 request per second load, it reports that 40 succeeded with 200 OK response and 20 requests were cancelled because client timeout exceeded while awaiting headers.

Now, I was trying to spot this on the server side. I can't see the timeouts logged either in apache access logs or gunicorn access logs. Note that I am interested in connections that weren't accepted as well as that are accepted and times out.

I have some experience working on similar services on Windows. The http.sys error logs would show connection dropped errors and we would know if our server was dropping connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a client times out, all the server knows is that the client has aborted the connection. In [`mod_log`'s config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html), the `%X` format specifier is used to log the status of the client connection after the request has completed, which is exactly what you want to know in this case.

[image: Screenshot from mod_log's config docs]

Configure your logs to use `%X`, and look for the `X` character in the log lines.

**Bonus:** I even found [the discussion](https://grokbase.com/t/apache/dev/0097aek7yk/logging-aborted-connections-in-the-access-log) about this feature in apache's dev forum, from 20 years ago

**Update:**
Regarding refused connections, these cannot be logged by apache. Connection refusal is done by the kernel, in the tcp stack, and not by apache. The closest solution including only apache that I can think of is keeping track of the amount of open connections (using `mod_status`). If it reaches the maximum you know you might be refusing connections. Otherwise, you'd need to set up some monitoring solution to track tcp resets sent by the kernel.

Comment: In your question, you state that "20 requests were cancelled because client timeout exceeded". As I wrote in my answer, usually when a client timeout is exceeded it means that the connection to the server has been accepted, but not yet processed. When the timeout is exceeded, the client aborts the connection and an X should be written in your log (when using %X).