# How to get the number of successful downloads of a 2 GB file by a client?

Tags: php, apache, download, authorization, x-sendfile

I need to deliver 2 GB files to clients (who receive a personal download token), I currently use this:

```
if (is_valid_download_token($token)) {
    log_download_start();  // logs token, date, IP
    header("X-Sendfile: /files/2GB_file.zip");
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="2GB_file.zip"');
}
```

I'd like my automated system to make sure:

- that they downloaded the file successfully *at least once* (I periodically run a script to check this)
- that there is *no more than 2* successful downloads for a given token (after this, I'll return a message)

**Thus, how to get the number of successful downloads of a 2 GB file by a client?**

Notes on what I've tried so far:

- Simply incrementing a counter in `log_download_start()` is not a good solution because someone might have to restart 5 times the download (because of a poor internet connection), until it finally works.
- Also, from the logs, I know people use "download managers" that split the 2 GB download into 20 download requests of 100 MB, which is totally fine. So just counting the number of requests at the start isn't efficient.
- I'm using PHP + Apache + `X-Sendfile` for the specific reasons explained in [Fastest Way to Serve a File Using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697748/fastest-way-to-serve-a-file-using-php/3731639#3731639) and [Downloading files with download.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989029/downloading-files-with-download-php/60914985#60914985). TL;DR: I don't want the 2 GB data to be read by PHP (which would slow down everything), instead I let Apache handle the request directly.

Comment: You might be able to spot the failed downloads in the Apache logs - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60366932/apache2-how-to-log-rejected-connections-and-client-timeout

Comment: @ADyson The problem is that if a download manager downloads the part #5 among 20 parts of 100 MB, it would probably be displayed as failed because not the whole 2 GB file is served, but in fact it's part of a successful download.